# Refresh LWC Component from AURA Component - Error : - 'forceRefreshInitiated' of undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-events

I'm trying to refresh LWC Component from AURA component. I need help in resolving the below error as i'm not able to figure out the issue here. Error :- 
**Uncaught Action failed: c:QuoteLineItemsAuraComponent$controller$closeModelAddProduct [Cannot read property 'forceRefreshInitiated' of undefined]**

Aura Component Code is as follows :-

```
<c:addProductsParentComponent style="padding:0px" recordId="{!v.recordId}" oncancelAndClose="{!c.closeModelAddProduct}">
        </c:addProductsParentComponent>

 <c:quoteLineItemRelatedList aura:id="messageBroker" style="padding:0px" recordId="{!v.recordId}"  oncancelAndClose="{!c.closeWindow}">
    </c:quoteLineItemRelatedList>
```

Aura JS Controller code is as follows :-

```
  closeModelAddProduct: function(component, event, helper) {
  // for Hide/Close Model,set the "openAddProductModal" attribute to "Fasle"
  component.find("messageBroker").forceRefreshInitiated();
     // refresh the view
    //$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
  component.set("v.openAddProductModal", false);
  component.set("v.showButtonDiv", true);

},
```

LWC JS code is as follows :-

```
 @api
 forceRefreshInitiated() {
    console.log('forceRefreshInitiated');
    refreshApex(this.refreshTable);
  }
```

TIA,
Sunil

Comment: No that dint help me to resolve my issue.

Comment: I think it does...You should be able to call as the answer mentions for this exact scenario `component.find("NameOfYourLWC").forceRefreshInitiated();`

Comment: My code is correct..but still i'm getting the error, that is the problem :) .  Is there a need to declare :-  <aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{! c.handleForceRefreshViewForLWC }"/> ..? I haven't declared this.